# How to resolve: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'

Tags: python, flask, mongoalchemy

I set up a MongoDB database, using MongoAlchemy and Flask in Python. The problem is that when I try to save an object into the database, I get this error, and I didn't found an answer on the internet. The problem seems to be with the parameter **safe** of the save function, but it shouldn't affect it in any way, because that parameter is optional. This is how my code looks:

```
    p1 = People(Name='Chis', Age=21, Password='abc', Vms=[

            {'Name': 'Virtual1',
             'Status': 'Active'},

            {'Name': 'Virtual2',
             'Status': 'Inactive'},

            {'Name': 'Virtual3',
             'Status': 'Active'}
        ])

    p1.save()
```

This is the full error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 64, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "app.py", line 26, in create_app
    insert_db.populateTables()
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/REST_API/api/blueprints/db/insert_db.py", line 45, in populateTables
    p1.save(safe=None)
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/FlaskServer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_mongoalchemy/__init__.py", line 275, in save
    self._session.insert(self, safe=safe)
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/FlaskServer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoalchemy/session.py", line 172, in insert
    self.add(item, safe=safe)
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/FlaskServer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoalchemy/session.py", line 188, in add
    return self.flush()
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/FlaskServer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoalchemy/session.py", line 414, in flush
    result = op.execute()
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/FlaskServer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoalchemy/ops.py", line 97, in execute
    return self.collection.save(self.data, safe=self.safe)
  File "/home/chis/IDEs/pycharm-community-2017.1.4/Projects/FlaskServer/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2440, in save
    write_concern = WriteConcern(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'safe'
```

Edit: script containing the People class

```
from init_db import db


class People(db.Document):
    Name = db.StringField()
    Age = db.IntField()
    Password = db.StringField()
    Vms = db.AnythingField()
```

Edit for future viewers: I managed to solve the issue by installing an older version of pymongo (preferably 2.9.0).

Comment: If you run the first command, without the `p1.save()`, does it work?

Comment: Please also post the definition of the People class in your post.

Comment: @Vinny: Yes, it does.

Comment: @MrLeeh Edited.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767548/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-password

Comment: https://github.com/cloudmesh/cloudmesh/issues/205

Comment: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1154

Comment: @CristianCoroian:  I didn't found an answer on the internet? Try English.

Comment: @Rahul: Not sure what did you mean with "Try English", but I managed to solve my issue with information from one of your links. Thank you.

Comment: @CristianCoroian: You said you tried searching internet. I said try searching in english.

Comment: @Rahul: Nice joke. I already visited the links you posted before posting the question, but apparently I didn't payed much attention.